# Javascript: Why does my input validation not work?

Tags: javascript

This is validation that i'm working on but can't seem to get right. When I input the correct pin "12345", it works and function Done() displays the alert "Well Done". However, we I input 3 failed attempts at the pin, it does display an error but function Done still activates when after the error the program should stop. Any solutions?

```
<head>
    <script>
        valid = false;

        function Start(valid) {


            check(valid);


            if (valid = true) {
                Done();
            }
            if (valid = false) {
                alert('End');
                return;
            }

        }

        function check(valid) {

            var PinNum;
            var Attempts = 0;


            while (Attempts < 3) {
                Attempts = (Attempts + 1);
                PinNum = prompt('Enter the pin number');

                if (PinNum == '12345') {
                    alert('Welcome!');
                    valid = true;
                    return valid;
                    return;
                } else {
                    alert('Wrong pin number, this is attemp ' + Attempts + ' of 3');
                }
            }
            alert('Too many failed attempts, giving up');
            return;
        }


        function Done() {
            alert("well done")
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="Start()">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Take debugger and debug your code

Comment: You just passed `valid` as argument making it local to the check function, so changing `valid` inside the check function does not affect `valid` outside the function, those are two different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if else` statement, you assigned `true` to `valid` instead of comparing them. You can simplify the statements to:

```
var valid = false;

function Start() {
    check();

    if (valid) {
        Done();
    } else {
        alert('End');
    }
}

function check() {

    var PinNum;
    var Attempts = 0;

    while (Attempts < 3) {
        Attempts = (Attempts + 1);
        PinNum = prompt('Enter the pin number');

        if (PinNum == '12345') {
            alert('Welcome!');
            valid = true;
            return;
        } else {
            alert('Wrong pin number, this is attemp ' + Attempts + ' of 3');
        }
    }
    alert('Too many failed attempts, giving up');
    return;
}


function Done() {
    alert("well done")
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mxSE6/)

Comment: But I need to make sure valid is true. With your method my function Done() does not work.

Comment: @user3746770, when `valid === true`, `if (valid)` is equivalent to `if (true)`. If that didn't fix it, there's some other problem

Comment: @user3746770, I've cleaned up your code. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

A few items:

1. The variable `valid` in your `Start` function is a different variable than the one you defined outside of the function. Every time you click the button, `undefined` is passed to the function. You should read up on JavaScript scope - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp
2. `valid = true` is an assignment. A single equals sign means "assign to" whereas a double or triple equal sign `===` mean to compare. You should read up on Comparison Operators - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp
3. Global variables are also considered bad practice, so it'd be better to avoid that `valid` variable altogether. Here's one possible solution - http://www.jasonbuckboyer.com/playground/stack-overflow/javascript-why-does-my-input-validation-not-work.html

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function start() {
    if (is_valid()) {
        Done();
    } else {
        alert('End');
        return;
    }
}
function is_valid() {
    var PinNum,
        Attempts = 0;
    while (Attempts < 3) {
        Attempts = (Attempts + 1);
        PinNum = prompt('Enter the pin number');
        if (PinNum == '12345') {
            alert('Welcome!');
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Wrong pin number, this is attempt ' + Attempts + ' of 3');
        }
    }
    alert('Too many failed attempts, giving up');
    return false;
}
function Done() {
    alert("well done")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```